# Light calculation issue

Tags: lighting, hdri, denoise

[image: Light calculation issue]

So I have tried so many things to get this blender denoiser to work properly on this image but I can't seem to figure it out. I am almost finished with this image but no matter how much I increase the resolution or samples nothing seems to fix this, I also tried every variation of denoising ... I would deeply appreciate any advise. Thank you !!!

- I do have an 8K HDRI installed

Comment: The image is very heavily compressed. To my eyes that looks like regular reflections and not noise, but that may be because of the compression. If the denoiser in 2.80 doesn't work well enough, then you could try the denoise node in 2.81. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/denoise.html?highlight=denoise

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot!